# would rather VS. would rather that

Tags: grammar

I would rather go home.

I would rather that I went home.

Could you tell me the difference between these?

Comment: The specific example makes it unclear what you're asking about. Is it really whether it makes any difference if you include *"that"* after *"rather"* (as per your question title)? Or the difference between *"I would rather you leave"* and *"I would rather you left"*, as implied by the examples?

Comment: This question is probably better answered at ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is a preference and the answer to

> Will you stay or will you go?

The other is a wish, subjunctive - a possible answer to

> We plan to keep you here for 3 more months, would you like that?